Unable to retrieve custom metadata of Azure Blob when using Azure AI Search service
I am using Azure AI Search ‘Import and vectorize data’ to import data from a blob storage

The Blobs have a custom metadata called ‘ragstatus’

In the Indexer, fieldMappings property, I have an entry for ‘ragstatus’

The same ‘ragstatus’ is added to the index as well

Indexer is set to extract ‘Data and Metadata’

Still when I search , ragstatus comes as null. What am I doing wrong here?


When you create new index using import and with ragstatus metadata already present in blob you will get the field directly in Customize target index tab as shown below.

But if you have already created index and indexer then you added metadata in blobs and, created ragstatus field in index you have to run the indexer again to reflect the changes and you no need to do field mappings in indexer.

If see here after adding metadata, 1 document is re indexed.
Output;


how do you set up field mappings in the indexer for metadata that has the key "ragstatus"?

The OP 1st image shows how to do field mappings. But in this scenario no need of field mappings. Indexer directly creates metadata for the first time else running the indexer again gets the data, make sure to create field in index before running the indexer again

do you mean by naming my index field the same as the blob metadata key that is sufficient?

You have run the indexer again after creating the metadata key name.

I did, even reset the indexer, also added new files with the same metadata key and still get null values in the index.

You remove the field mappings for ragstatus field from indexer

Also try recreating the index.

after recreating the index it succeeded, thanks a lot for helping (even off topic!)
